# Sortable for long lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have to implement [jquery's sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) in my project.

I am creating it dynamically.

But the problem is that the number of items in the list are more than 100. So,if a user wants to bring 100th item to top, he has to drag the 100th item from bottom of the page ( has to scroll while holding click ), which is too much cumbersome. So, what approach should i have to implement this 'draggable' behaviour ( without using any extra plugin ) ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have two instances of the list side by side, with separate scroll bars. This way the user could scroll the left one to the source location and the right one to the destination location, and drag the item from one side to the other.